# Reordering divs when page responds to mobile/tablet

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

At the moment I have 4 full width divs (each div is: half text, quarter image, quarter image), I want this to change to 8 full width divs (full image, full text x4) on tablet/mobile.

So far using media queries, I have hidden one image and made the other full width but the order isn't image, text, image, text etc. It's image, text, text, image, image, text, text, image.

Is there a way of reordering these divs with the media queries, so they are in the correct order? (image, text, image, text etc).

```css
.full-width {
    padding: 20px 170px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 710px) {
    .hidden_img {
        display: none !important;
    }
 .item-image {
 width:100% !important;
 height: 200px !important; 
 }
 .item-text {
  width: 100% !important;
 }
}
.item-image {
 width: 24%;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 background-size: cover;
}
#private_1 {
 background: url("www.kentunion.co.uk/pageassets/venue-hire/private_1.png") no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
}
#private_2 {
 background: url("www.kentunion.co.uk/pageassets/venue-hire/private_2.png") no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
}
#corp_1 {
 background: url("www.kentunion.co.uk/pageassets/venue-hire/corp_1.png") no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
}
#corp_2 {
 background: url("www.kentunion.co.uk/pageassets/venue-hire/corp_2.png") no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
}
#ticket_1 {
 background: url("www.kentunion.co.uk/pageassets/venue-hire/ticket_1.png") no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
}
#ticket_2 {
 background: url("www.kentunion.co.uk/pageassets/venue-hire/ticket_2.png") no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
}
#day_1 {
 background: url("www.kentunion.co.uk/pageassets/venue-hire/day_1.png") no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
}
#day_2 {
 background: url("www.kentunion.co.uk/pageassets/venue-hire/day_2.png") no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
}
.booking-container {
     background: url("www.kentunion.co.uk/pageassets/venue-hire/venue_booking_banner.jpg") no-repeat right 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
 padding: 20px;
 margin-top: 30px;
}
.item-text p, .item-text h4, #intro_text {
font-size: 16px !important;
text-align: center;
}
.item-text {
 width:50%;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px 50px;

}
.event_info{
font-size: 16px !important;
}

.item {
 width: 100%;
 height: 250px;
 display: table;
 table-layout: fixed;
}


div {
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline: 0;
}
.content-spacing {
 padding: 0 !important;
}
#intro_text {
 padding: 1% 9%;
}
```

```html
<div id="private" class="item">
   <div class="item-image" id="private_1" style="margin-right:2%;">
   </div>
   <div class="item-image hidden_img" id="private_2">
   </div>
   <div class="item-text">
    <h4>PRIVATE HIRE</h4>
    <p class="event_info">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="private" class="item">
   <div class="item-text">
    <h4>CORPORATE EVENTS</h4>
    <p class="event_info">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="item-image" style="margin-right:2%;" id="corp_1">
   </div>
   <div class="item-image hidden_img" id="corp_2">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="private" class="item">
   <div class="item-image" style="margin-right:2%;" id="ticket_1">
   </div>
   <div class="item-image hidden_img" id="ticket_2">
   </div>
   <div class="item-text">
    <h4>TICKETED EVENTS</h4>
    <p class="event_info">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="private" class="item">
   <div class="item-text">
    <h4>DAY EVENTS</h4>
    <p class="event_info">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="item-image" style="margin-right:2%;" id="day_1">
   </div>
   <div class="item-image hidden_img" id="day_2">
   </div>
  </div>
```

.

Comment: Are you sure your structure is right? It seems a little off for me.

Comment: If you don't have to support old browsers (pre IE10) I recommend that you switch to use the flexbox model. It can do what you want and more in a much simpler way... Here you have a good link to start: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: As general rule, if a solution seems overly complex, then it probably is.

Answer (score 0):

Before all else, You are using an `id`of `private` for all Your containers. This is wrong. ID's should be for unique elements. You should be using a `class="private"` beacuse Your items are repeating.

If browser support is not an issue for Your project at hand, I would suggest using **[CSS Flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** for Your content. By using this approach, You can manage the order of Your elements by using the **[CSS Order property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/order)** which allows you more flexibility with Your media-queries.

In Your specific case, you need to set a `display: flex;` property for the container and then using media queries, attach the `order` property to each of the elements within Your container. The numbering here starts from `0` , therefore, your elements will be numbered `order: 0` for first, `order: 1` for the second and etc.

Something like:

```
  .item {
    display: flex;
  }

  .item .item-image {
    order: 0;
  }

  .item .item-text {
    order: 1;
  }

  .item .item-image.hidden_img {
    order: 2;
  }
```